# How to output special characters in Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I am trying to output currency symbols in [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com) with a helper method like this:

```
def price(number)
  @view.number_to_currency(number, :unit => "&euro;")
end
```

I then use it like this:

```
price(@invoice.total)
```

Unfortunately it's not working and instead of `€` I get `&euro;` in my PDF documents.

(The same `number_to_currency` function works great outside of Prawn by the way.)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it by just using special characters like `€` instead of HTML-entities like `&euro;`. I had to tweak my app a bit to achieve that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [railscast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn) under the heading "Formatting The Currency Fields". Looks like you don't have to escape the the currency symbols.

Comment: Yes, my application is based on that tutorial. Yet the currency units are pulled from a legacy database in my case. So I have to work with the HTML-entities outlined above. And that doesn't work.